# Symfony my url gets an id instead of a slug

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I've created a function that when you select a customer, it retrieves information about the customer, such as the type of policy associated and the commission rate linked to this type of policy. In my controller, there's a method that retrieves the client via its slug. The rest is done using ajax in the template. Only when I select the client, the URL receives an unknown id instead of the slug and i have the error Client not found. Please help

```
/**
 * @Route("/get-client-donnees/{slug}", name="get-data-client", methods={"GET"})
 */

public function ClientData($slug, ClientsRepository $clientsRepository)
{
  // Récupérez le client en fonction du slug
  // $clientRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Clients::class);
  $client = $clientsRepository->findOneBy(['slug' => $slug]);

  if (!$client) {
    return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Client not found'], 404);
  }

  // Récupérez la police associée au client (vous devrez adapter cela en fonction de votre logique métier)
  $police = $client->getPolicies()->first();

  if (!$police) {
    return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Police not found for the client'], 404);
  }

  // Récupérez le type de police associé à la police
  $typePolice = $police->getTypePolice();

  if (!$typePolice) {
    return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'TypePolice not found for the police'], 404);
  }

  // Récupérez le taux associé au type de police
  $rate = $typePolice->getRate();

  // Retournez le type de police et le taux au format JSON
  $data = [
    'typePolice' => $typePolice->getName(),
    'rate' => $rate,
  ];

  return new JsonResponse($data);
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Détecte les changements dans le champ client
  $('#primes_police').on('change', function() {
    var slug = $(this).val();

    // Faites une requête AJAX pour récupérer le type de police et le taux en fonction du client
    $.ajax({
      url: '/get-client-donnees/' + slug,
      method: 'GET',
      success: function(data) {
        // Met à jour le champ typePolice avec le type de police récupéré
        $('#primes_typePolice').val(data.typePolice);

        // Met à jour le champ rate avec le taux récupéré
        $('#primes_rate').val(data.rate);
      },
      error: function() {
        console.error('Erreur lors de la récupération du type de police et du taux.');
      }
    });
  });

  // Détecte les changements dans le champ primeNet
  $('#primes_netPrime').on('input', function() {
    // Récupère les valeurs des champs
    var primeNet = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
    var rate = parseFloat($('#primes_rate').val()) || 0;

    // Effectue le calcul de la commission
    var commission = primeNet * rate;

    // Met à jour le champ commission
    $('#primes_commission').val(commission);
  });
});
```

Comment: Probabiliy you are filling `#primes_police` field with an invalid valuie.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the `slug` passed with jQuery with the slug in your Controller and database:

```
$('#primes_police').on('change', function () {
   var slug = $(this).val();             
   console.log(slug);
   //.....
    
    
public function ClientData($slug, ClientsRepository $clientsRepository){
    dd($slug);
    //.....
```